# Select all newly entered values per unique column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

```
drop table if exists aa;
create temporary table aa(`Country` varchar(100),`Month_Year` varchar(100),
                `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp());
insert into aa(Country,Month_Year,created_at) 
    values('Spain1','JUN2020','2020-09-03 14:20:20'), 
            ('Spain2','JUN2020','2020-09-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain3','JUN2020','2020-08-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain4','JUN2020','2020-07-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain5','JUN2020','2020-06-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain6','JUL2020','2020-09-01 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain7','JUL2020','2020-09-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain8','JUN2020','2020-09-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain9','AUG2020','2020-09-01 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain10','AUG2020','2020-05-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Spain11','AUG2020','2020-05-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Porto1','AUG2019','2020-05-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Porto2','AUG2019','2020-05-03 14:20:20'),
            ('Porto2','AUG2019','2020-05-03 13:20:20'),
            ('Porto2','AUG2011','2020-05-03 13:20:20');
select * from aa;
```

Produces:

[image]

How to modify the `select` query, in order to leave only the highlighted columns? The logic is that per unique value in `Month_Year` column, only the rows with the newest `created_at` per unique `Month_Year` are left.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wEuUpiDyEHq8SZtLDpBm5Q/0#

Comment: I would suggest storing month/year as a `date` with the day set to the first. This will be more efficient on storage, sortable, indexable, and give you access to [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You can add a `check(dayofmonth(month_year) = 1)`.

Comment: @Schwern - thanks, you definitely have a point concerning efficiency. Still, for the sake of the question, it may be considered that the `Month_Year` column is a hash function of something random, repeated on the same places as the month and year are repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option filters with a subquery:

```
select t.*
from aa t
where t.created_at = (
    select max(t1.created_at)
    from aa t1
    where t1.month_year = t.month_year
)
order by created_at desc
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7d29f55ff6f3c573aec0887415b87b5

Comment: Somehow I am changing `mytable` with `aa` and I get this error - *Query Error: Error: ER_CANT_REOPEN_TABLE: Can't reopen table: 't'*

Comment: @Vityata: don't use a temporary table. Use a regular table instead, [like this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7d29f55ff6f3c573aec0887415b87b5).